gRPC 1.47.4 vs2017 compilation errors
In my company we try to create packages of gRPC and all dependencies in our private conan repository. Currently we stuck with gcc6.4.0 and VS2017. I had currently created packages for these dependencies:
abseil-cpp: "20210324.2"
c-ares: "1.28.1"
protobuf: "3.21.12"
re2: "2023-03-01"
openssl: "1.1.1s"
zlib: "1.2.13"
And now to the point. I can compile gRPC 1.47.4 under linux and macos, but under windows I get errors like that:
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z] C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\be3a4e\1\include\absl/meta/type_traits.h(166): error C2280: 'absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>>::operator =(const absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function [C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\7e4d97\1\_bld.Debug\_src\grpc.vcxproj]
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           with
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           [
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]               T0=grpc_core::Pending,
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]               Child=grpc_core::ReclaimerQueue::Handle
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z] C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\be3a4e\1\include\absl/meta/type_traits.h(166): error C2280: 'absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>>::operator =(const absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function [C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\7e4d97\1\_bld.Debug\_src\grpc_unsecure.vcxproj]
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           with
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           [
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]               T0=grpc_core::Pending,
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]               Child=grpc_core::ReclaimerQueue::Handle
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           ] (compiling source file C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\7e4d97\1\_src\src\core\ext\filters\census\grpc_context.cc)
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z] C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\be3a4e\1\include\absl/meta/type_traits.h(166): error C2280: 'absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>>::operator =(const absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function [C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\7e4d97\1\_bld.Debug\_src\grpc_unsecure.vcxproj]
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           with
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           ] (compiling source file C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\7e4d97\1\_src\src\core\ext\filters\census\grpc_context.cc)
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           [
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]               T0=grpc_core::Pending,
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]               Child=grpc_core::ReclaimerQueue::Handle
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z]           ] (compiling source file C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\7e4d97\1\_src\src\core\ext\filters\channel_idle\channel_idle_filter.cc)
[2024-06-20T14:18:33.372Z] C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\be3a4e\1\include\absl/meta/type_traits.h(166): error C2280: 'absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>>::operator =(const absl::lts_20210324::variant_internal::Union<T0,grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<Child>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function [C:\j\w@tmp\.cnn\7e4d97\1\_bld.Debug\_src\grpc.vcxproj]

The strange thing is that I compiled that locally without errors, but on our CI/CD pipeline these errors shows during compilation.
I updated abseil libraries to supported version (patch 2), I tried many setting, force C++14 standard without extensions. I want to compile gRPC without errors, but I do not knwo how resolve that error :/ Could you help me?

Are you using the recipes from the https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index repository as-is? Or are those your own recipes?
It would be necessary to compare the output logs from your local machine with the output logs of the CI server. For doing that, SO might not be the best forum, and Github tickets might be better: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

@drodri we use custom recipes, because we use old CMake generator. Currently I trying to download docker build agent image to check version of compiler and etc.

Ok, please lets follow up in github issues, it will be easier.

@drodri I resolve that problem, we used too old VS2017 MSBuildTools 14.11. After update to 14.16 grpc compiles without errors.
